# Trouble Saving ID to Resource File

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have been working on an Android Application project recently, and I've notice that some of my code IDs within a XML file will not register within the R file, and I have not been able to access the IDs within my classes. The code within the XML file will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_height="250dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:id="@+id/ivReturnedPic" 
android:layout_width="250dp"></ImageView>

<ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:id="@+id/ibTakePic" 
android:layout_width="125dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageButton>

<Button android:text="Set Wallpaper" 
android:id="@+id/bSetWall" 
android:layout_width="125dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

None of theses IDs will register within the resource file.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct R file in your code? Make sure you don't have android.R as one of your imports. If you do, delete it and import the R file for your project. (like import com.package.packagename.R; )

Comment: I'm a little confused on what the line: import com.package.packagename.R means. I imported my name, but I get the following error: "- Syntax error on token "package", Identifier 
  expected" Help?

Answer (score 1):

There's problem in your xml that's why R is not being generated automatically

Remove one of extra `</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

you must be sure that the image "icon.png" or "icon.jpg" is under your res/drawable folder.

```
android:src="@drawable/icon"
```